# Partitioning a simple follower table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

What would be the best way to partition a simple follower table, which has a primary key on (user_id,follower_id) and also has an index on (follower_id)?

We make select queries with both user_id and follower_id.
If we split data based on user_id, we will not be able to retrieve full results based on follower_id from within the same table.
Duplicating the table to separate following-follower tables, and partitioning each table based on their own primary keys seemed like an option but we are not sure about it.

The table currently has 10 million records and it is growing rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONing` does not inherently provide any performance benefit.  In fact, it sometimes slows down the processing.  There are 4 [*use cases*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) where `PARTITION` is beneficial; your description does not seem to be one of them.

Is the user::follower relationship symmetrical?  That is, if a I am "following" you, are you necessarily "following" me?  (The answer may lead to a different way of structuring the data.)

For a many:many relationship, which this sounds like, follow the guidelines [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).  Presumably you have one "Users" table, and the relationship is between that table and itself.

I don't (yet) see where you will have any problem with non-partitioning and the many:many table.  What are you concerned about?

To further discuss, please provide tentative `CREATE TABLE` *and* `SELECTs`.